# Can I conditionally choose what variable I assign a value to?

Tags: python, variable-assignment, ternary

I know that you can do things like this in Python:

```
var = value1 if( booleanCheck() ) else value2
```

What I want to know is if I can conditionally choose which var I place a value into with a similar sort of structure?

something like this:

```
(var1 if( booleanCheck() ) else var2) = value
```

In my case specifically I'm trying to assign a child node to the correct side in a Binary Search Tree, I know I can just do a normal if block but I was trying to challenge myself to using minimal space.

Comment: No, you really do not want to do that.

Comment: why you need that??? i don't think any use in it

Comment: Just use a normal if/else structure here.

Comment: Maybe if you give as a wider perspective of what is going on here, we can guide you to the right direction. I'm almost certain you have an XY problem - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: "I was trying to challenge myself to using minimal space" - I think the OP has at least a partial non-XY problem impetus for this question, but very interesting concept, @ElmoVanKielmo!

Answer (score 4):

Well theoretically you could do something like this, if both variables are already defined:

```
var1, var2 = (value, var2) if booleanCheck() else (var1, value)
```

Not saying that you should do it, though.

Answer (score 2):

Since the use case is assigning to the correct side of a binary tree, I assume the assignment targets are actually attributes of some tree node, and the usual code would be

```
if condition:
    node.left = value
else
    node.right = value
```

This code could be replaced by

```
setattr(node, "left" if condition else "right", value)
```

or alternatively

```
vars(node)["left" if condition else "right"] = value
```

It *could* be replaced by this, but it really *shouldn't*.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very good form to use `locals` or `globals` in this way (confusing, not often used, hard to debug, terrible performance), but it can be done:

```
varname = 'a' if some_condition else 'b'
locals()[varname] = value # or globals()
print locals()[varname] # or globals()
```

I think the real challenge here is to resist seemingly "fancy" or "creative" code and write code that others will understand immediately. Not to mention yourself if you have to come back to it later. But it is worth it to know what funky code (as in old cheese) looks like.

Comment: You can't modify the dictionary returned by `locals()`.  It might work in some cases, like in the global scope, but in general it doesn't, see the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals).

Comment: I don't think that's right. In my 2.7.5 interpreter, I can write a function that writes a new key:value pair and reads the value, both using `locals()`. Could you explain where it doesn't work?

Comment: In general, it doesn't work whenever you are inside a function using fast locals (most functions not using `exec` fall into this category).  Moreover, it doesn't matter whether you find a specific version of a specific Python implementation that happens to execute this code in the way you expect -- the language specification says you can't do this, so you can't rely on this to work portably.

Comment: Thanks for editing your comment with the docs link. But obviously I recommended the OP not use this approach anyway (as everyone else has as well).

Answer (score 0):

Unlike `locals()`, `globals()` is documented to be updateable (as it returns the `__dict__` of the current module). I routinely use `vars()` *in the global scope* - which is the same *in that case* - to reduce code duplication:

```
for v,ar in ('a',x),('b',y): vars()[v]=fn(ar)
```

For some others objects (like the current class/instance), `__dict__`'s members are accessible as syntactic variables, too:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        vars(self).update(v,locals()[v] for v in 'a','b')
        do_something(self.a)
```

Do note, however, that:

- These "syntactic references" reduce code maintainability - as they are harder to find - and thus will likely upset code checking tools like `pylint`.
- a need to use variables in such a way typically *signifies an attempt to use a scope as a `dict`:* such variables tend to be "homogenous" in some way, asking for being used in array operations, and thus should probably be combined into a dedicated container instead.

  - this goes double when variable names are autogenerated - and also runs the risk of collisions. See also [How can you dynamically create variables via a while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-in-python-via-a-while-loop) on this.